# Using R code to scrape data from a webpage into an Excel file

Tags: html, r, excel, web-scraping

I have written a code in R which is supposed to retrieve certain information from a website and import it into an Excel file. I have used it for one website and it works, but for this particular website, it has an issue, it returns N/A values in excel, and I don't know why.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rvest)
library(string)
library(rebus)
library(lubridate)
library(xlsx)
library(reader)

setwd("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Tenders")
getwd()

ran=seq(300100,300000,-1)
result = data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(ran), ncol = 1))
colnames(result) <- c("111")


for (i in ran){
    url <- paste0("http://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/?go=", i)
    
    download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
    content <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")
    
    
    #111
    status=content %>% html_nodes("#print_area tr:nth-child(1) td + td")%>% html_text()
    status[length(status) == 0] <- NA
    status=as.data.frame(status)
    status=(if (nrow(status)>1){
      a=as.matrix(paste(unlist(status), collapse =" "))
    } else {as.matrix(status)
      
    })
    result[i, 1]=status
}

s=as.data.frame(ran)
final=result[-c(1:s[nrow(s),]),]
#Excel
write.xlsx(final,"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Tenders.xlsx", sheetName = "111")
```

I am using selector gadget tool, which is a chrome extension for identifying HTML parts that the code is supposed to use to gather the information (for example, in the code above it is "#print_area tr:nth-child(1) td + td", which is the first entry in the link).

Can someone help me find out what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you provide a single url from which you want to scrape?

Comment: Can you provide your sample output what you require?